Ruling over punishment imposed for violating a restriction imposed over permissible act by Ruler
Is imposing punishment if someone engages in permissible thing but the permissible act is restricted by the ruler correct as per Fiqh?
إضاءات حول قاعدة تقييد المباح
اقرأ المزيد في إسلام أون لاين: https://islamonline.net/%D8%A5%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AD/
This article clarify matter regarding restricting what is permissible but there is no discussion whether the punishment imposed by the authority after restricting what is permissible is valid as per Sharia or not?

Examples for better understanding
Govt. restricts govt employees from working in any other job apart
from govt job till he is a govt employee. If an employee engages or
works part-time after working hours, authorities don't punish him/her
if they found out
While in another scenario govt punishes the employee

So Are these punishment valid as per Sharia?
